# How to remove invisible [ZWSP] from string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a String(assume str) received from some DB query.
str = "+Aa​+Bk​+Bo​+Ac​+Lc​";
But if copied the same string to intelliJ, It shows the invisible chars in str

[image]

I have to split this String (i.e.str) to String[] and then to List.
And getting this[ZWSP] in splatted Array and in converted List as well.
Also tried few/following techniques to trim and remove this, but did not worked.

```
        String str = "+Aa​+Bk​+Bo​+Ac​+Lc​";
        String[] strArr = str.split("\\+");

        List<String> splitStrList = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\+"))
                .map(String::trim)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---Approach 2

```
        String[] array2 = Arrays.stream(strArr).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
       
        String[] trimmedArray = new String[array2.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            trimmedArray[i] = array2[i].trim();
        }
        List<String> trimmedArrayList = Arrays.asList(trimmedArray);
```

Also few other approach, but while copying the output to intelliJ IDE seeing those [ZWSP] special chars.
[image]
**That is creating issue in further processing.**

How Can be these spcl chars i.e [ZWSP] removed to get List/Array like
**[, Aa​, Bk​, Bo​, Ac​, Lc​]**

Will Appreciate all suggestions/solutions to this problem.

Comment: It's called a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), and the whitespace catch for regex will grab them: `String[] strArr = str.split("\\s+")` (note the missing `s` in your regex).

Comment: @Rogue ("\\s+") also didn't working, its removing the available chars as well creating the list of length 1.

Answer (score 2):

That character it's called [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) as @Rogue mentions. You could use unicode character to remove it:

```
str.replace("\u200B", "");
```

Or you could split the string like:

```
str.split("\\+\u200B");
```

And then process the array as you need.

See:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: Use `replace`, not `replaceAll`.  The latter uses a regular expression, which has no benefit for a constant string with no metacharacters.

Comment: I agree @VGR. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks @admlz635 !!  str.replace("\u200B", ""); worked ..